# What color is solid methane?

Tags: phase, color, hydrocarbons

Is it blueish, perfect white or some other color? I am interested because some celestial bodies are said to be covered with methane ice.

Comment: Are you referring to solid methane or methane clathrates?

Comment: @bon to solid methane

Comment: Very interesting question, particularly with recent discoveries in mind.

Comment: The answer may have to do with light scattering rather than absorption, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: [This](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/cassini/whycassini/cassini20130108_prt.htm) article appears to suggest that methane ice is colourless. `Scientists haven't entirely figured out what color the ice would be, though they suspect it would be colorless, as it is on Earth`

Comment: gaseous methane is **colorless** and a property like color depend on electron transfer between molecular or atomic orbitals and the energy of these orbitals is *independent* to temperature.so methane in solid state(low temperature and high pressure)is still colorless.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. For more information in general have a look at the [help]. I do not believe this is true. For example, carbon dioxide in the gas phase is colourless, but as a solid it is shiny white. Or consider water, in its solid state the colour rages from transparent to white to blue depending on the modification (pressure).

Comment: water  in solid form can be white but i didn't see blue ice. furthermore after solidification water become turbid instead of transparent. liquid water can pass light through itself  but when it become solid, solid water is turbid it is mean that light can't pass through it,  because ice can't absorb light it reflect all the visible wavelength and appear  white. i have same opinion about solid methane.

Comment: I was talking about the appearance, sorry to be imprecise. But here is what I was thinking about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_ice_(glacial)

Comment: Check color of oxygen in different phases - perceived color depends strongly on concentration and in gas it's very low.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is not very specific. So the answer is **it depends.** Think of water as an analog.

- Methane "snow" would be white. (Due to scattering of light).
- Solid methane under sufficient pressure would form a clear colorless solid.
- Methane "snow" (which would be on surface" of some celestial body) could be any color if contaminated by even small amounts of other hydrocarbons. A reddish color seems to be typical. See ref: http://www.caltech.edu/news/astronomers-find-ice-and-possibly-methane-snow-white-distant-dwarf-planet-1714

Comment: Can you provide a reference for your claims?